# Why is Magento forcing me to log in before I can add a product to cart?

Tags: magento, authentication, cart

I'm developing an ecommerce site using Magento v. 1.7.0.2 and for some reason,
every time I try to add a product to cart on the front end, the system requires
that I log in before it will let me add it.

I have Guest Checkout enabled and none of my test products are downloadable.

Interestingly, it only happens on Windows. I clear the cache in all my browsers on Windows
and try it and I get the log in / register screen whenever I try to add a product to cart.

If I test it on the Mac, though, it works perfectly.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Many thanks!

Cynthia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem. Believe it or not, it was a CSS error on my part.
I had the wishlist link div overlapping the add to cart button, in effect
covering it up w/ the wishlist link.

So while it *looked* like I was clicking on Add to Cart, I was actually adding
the item to my wishlist, which cannot be done w/o being a logged in, registered
user.

Sigh...big DOH! on my part.

The moral of this story is: always check your code!

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

1. on your config if guest checkout is enabled from system > configuration > checkout
2. on your products, if they are downloadable then they only can be purchased by registered users

Comment: Guest checkout is enabled and none of the products are downloadable.

Comment: doulecheck then all store scopes, clear cache , echo out the config variable as well to see if it is really set